# What is the relation between the main() method and main thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, program-entry-point

My tutor told me that the main thread is the parent thread of every thread, but he is not able to explain why.

When I write a simple program:

```
Class A{}
```

Then it at the time of execution it throws an exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main Exception in thread "main"
```

Is there any relation between the `main()` method and the main thread?

Comment: Your tutor is wrong. There is no parent-child relationship among Java threads.

Comment: of course, thread main is the start of the application, JVM creates a [thread(main)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616109/Java-Thread-Tutorial#maintr) and call the static main class by it

Comment: @EJP: "wrong" is harsh. While the threads don't carry that relationship, it can be said that all user threads are spawned (directly or indirectly) from the Main thread.

Comment: @EJP I agree you he is not write , There is no concept of parent and child thread . But what can i do to prove him this he is not correct at Main is Parent Thread

Comment: @Thilo No, "wrong" is *correct,* and according to the OP the tutor said 'parent of *every* thread', not just 'all user threads'. You can't have a parent-child relationship among siblings.

Comment: @EJP: In case of doubt (and second-hand citations by self-acknowledged Java newbies count as "doubt") I would not fault the tutor. "what can i do to prove him this he is not correct" That is exactly the wrong approach to communication with teaching assistants (unless you really know better then them).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> Is there any relation between main() method and Main Thread ?

When the JVM starts, it creates a thread called "Main". Your program will run on this thread, unless you create additional threads yourself.

The first thing the "Main" thread does is to look for your `static void main(String[] argv)` method and invoke it. That is the entry-point to your program.

If you want things to happen "at the same time", you can create multiple threads, and give each something to execute. They will then continue to do these things concurrently. The JVM also creates some internal threads for background work such as garbage collection.

Comment: If first thing "_Main_" Thread do is to search `static void main(String args[])` Then how come **static block** runs first .

Comment: That's how class loading works. Try to invoke a method on a new class, and it will load the class and initialize it (including running static initializer blocks). Nothing special about "main" there.

Comment: @java_begin - without main method, you can not run the program, so no static execution.

Comment: @Java_begins When you attempt to run a class, that class must have the `static void main(String[])` method.  The *static block* (if the class has one) will execute first, but it won't execute at all unless the main() method exists.
I guess you could say that the "_Main_" thread first verifies the existence of the main() method, then it initializes the class.  As @Thilo said, this involves executing the static block.  Once the class is loaded, the main() method is executed.

Answer (score 11):

Firstly `Main Thread is a parent thread of every thread` is ambiguous. Unlike `Process`, in Java threads there is no concept of parent and child. You do have `ThreadGroups` to group Threads and then have child groups, but it is different from `Process` in the sense that if parent dies, the child still remains.

The `main` thread is the thread that starts your program, or simply which runs your `public static void main(String... args)` method.