# What is a Thread? How many threads does my program have?

Tags: java, multithreading, class, program-entry-point

I know how to create a thread but I still don't understand what a thread is! What's the default thread? I know a default thread starts the main() but what starts the default thread? How can I calculate the threads in my program. I know it has been asked many times but I still haven't got a convincing answer.

Comment: There's way too much to explain here. Learn what a thread is. Then read all those related questions on the right. Maybe start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669159/what-is-the-relation-between-the-main-method-and-main-thread-in-java?rq=1).

Comment: The JVM starts the main thread, which can in turn start other threads.

Comment: A thread is a conceptual CPU execution unit -- something that executes the instructions of a program one at a time.  Since this is conceptual/virtual there is a potentially unlimited number of threads.